# VerifyError exclusively on LG smartphones

Tags: android

I have an app in google play store (Vocalizzo Lite) and the latest release crashes with

```
java.lang.VerifyError: at java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java) at 
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (AppComponentFactory.java:69) at 
androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (CoreComponentFactory.java) at 
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1216) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2932) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3156) at 
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78) at 
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108) at 
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68) at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1864) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106) at 
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:205) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6991) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java) at 
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(RuntimeInit.java:493) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main 
(ZygoteInit.java:884)
```

I see none of my own classes in this callstack. Fails happen only on LG devices, which is weird to me too (LGE LG G7 ThinQ, LGE LG Stylo 5, LGE Q8, and so on, 11 different models, SDK api 28 and 29). Any ideas how to investigate this?

Kind regards...

UPDATE: I got a physical LG device and could start my app with debugger. I got weird errors on it, but they are different. If I simply run the debug release type on it, I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.vitvlkv.vocalizzo.lite, PID: 30139
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getTracks()Ljava/util/List; in class Lcom/leff/midi/MidiFile; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.leff.midi.MidiFile' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
        at ru.vitvlkv.vocalizzo.util.MidiUtils.writeToStream(MidiUtils.java:43)
        at ru.vitvlkv.vocalizzo.util.MidiUtils.clone(MidiUtils.java:28) ...
```

Which is weird, because this is a class in my codebase, and THERE IS a method getTracks().

If I start the app in debug mode, then debugger catches:
`SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x0))` which could be a problem in native library (and the root cause of all the other weird stuff?..) which I use in my app.

Any recommedations on how to debug it now?..

Comment: are you using proguard/r8?

Comment: Yes, I do use R8.